# Configuring Bind - Error About SOA Record When Starting named Service

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, centos6

It's been entirely too long since I setup a bind server. I've creating a lot of Windows DNS servers lately so I wanted to try my hand at it on CentOS 6. Unfortunately I'm having a slew of trouble setting up the zone files.

Host Name: shield.domain.com

When I try to start the service I get the following error message:

```
domain.com.zone:3: SOA record not at top of zone (domain.com.domain.com)
zone domain.com/IN: loading from master file domain.com.zone failed: not at top of zone
zone domain.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
_default/domain.com/IN: not at top of zone
zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
```

I modified the /etc/named.conf file to include my new zone and the file is setup as so:

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { localhost; };
    recursion yes;

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    forwarders { <IP_ADDR_1>;<IP_ADDR_2>;<IP_ADDR_3>;};
};

zone "domain.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "domain.com.zone";
    allow-update { none; };
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

I then created a new zone file /var/named/domain.com.zone which is configured as such. I can't figure out what I did wrong with the SOA record at the top, or if there are other issues with my zone file:

```
$ORIGIN domain.com
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     shield.domain.com.    hostmaster.domain.com. (
                    2013008413      ; serial
                    21600           ; refresh after 6 hours
                    3600            ; retry after 1 hour
                    604800          ; expire after 1 week
                    86400 )         ; minimum TTL of 1 day

    IN      NS      shield.domain.com.

            IN      A       10.10.0.175

shield      IN      A       10.10.0.175
```

I used the following resources and I just find myself getting more and more lost staring blankly at the zone file. This is the only server in the environment multi-hosting different services:

Bind Configuration Files: http://centos.org/docs/2/rhl-rg-en-7.2/s1-bind-configuration.html

DNS Sample Zone: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/mydomain.html

Comment: Are you certain that those logs are with these exact config files?  It seems like your `$ORIGIN` line might be a mismatch with your `zone "domain.com" IN` configuration.  Do those configurations match *exactly*?  Try just removing the `$ORIGIN` line completely to see if that helps.

Comment: Like a charm. If you post it as an answer I will give you credit. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad that it worked!  Added an answer with a bit more elaboration/context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log entry `SOA record not at top of zone (domain.com.domain.com)` is a hint that something is amiss; the `SOA` record at the top of the file is not being considered as the entry for the domain that's supposed to be handled by this zone file.

This could be caused by the `$ORIGIN domain.com` line mismatching from the `zone "domain.com" IN {` line in the `named.conf` file, either due to an actual mismatched or something like a UTF-8 string handling problem.

An easy workaround in this case is to simply remove the `$ORIGIN` line from the zone file; it will then be automatically built based on the zone definition in `named.conf`, ensuring that those strings will match.

Comment: Specifically, `$ORIGIN domain.com` mismatches because it lacks a trailing dot. The end result is a `SOA` record of `domain.com.domain.com.`.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. The sad part is I do know this is how DNS works. I guess I've been pampered working with Windows DNS servers because it typically appends the period at the end if it realizes it's missing. I added $ORIGIN at the top again ensuring the period was added. Service started successfully.

Answer (score 0):

nobody appears to have seen, that you just forgot the dot at the end of your origin domain ... just like I appear to not have seen, that this thread is 9 years old